# ECMASCRIPT 6 <script type="text/traceur">

Tags: inheritance

I have a question if you can solve.
I have this script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="traceur.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/traceur">

  class Animal {
    constructor(name,weight,year) {
      this.name = name;
      this.weight = weight+"lb";
      this.year = year;
    }
    summary() {
     alert(this.name + " " + this.weight + "  " + this.year)
    }
  }

  class Cow extends Animal {
    constructor(x, y, z, mammal) {
      super(x, y, z);   
      this.mammal = mammal;
      }


  }
var cow1=new Cow('Luli',176,'09/01/2009',true);
cow1.summary();



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a question I can´t solve:
How I can export the code  to a file js and html called from the class Cow like as this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <script src="traceur.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="class.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/traceur">

var cow1=new Cow('Luli',176,'09/01/2009',true);
cow1.summary();



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error Message
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word class.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cow is not defined**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The script type for the class.js file has to be "text/traceur" so the traceur compile can load it.

`<script src="class.js" type="text/traceur"></script>`